# Thymeleaf th:each only displaying first element in dropdown menu

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, thymeleaf, dropdown

I'm trying to create a dropdown menu by iterating through objects using th:each. However my implementation only displays the first object instead of all of them. My relevant code :

```
    <tr th:each="user : ${userList}">
        <th scope="row"><span th:text="${user.id}"></span></th>
        <td><span th:text="${user.username}"></span></td>
        <td><span th:text="${user.email}"></span></td>
        <td width="60">
            <div class="dropdown">
                <button class="btn btn-light btn-block dropdown-toggle text-right" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown"><span th:text="${user.roles[0].role}"></span>
                    <span class="caret"></span></button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" th:each="role : ${user.roles}">
                    <li><a href="#"><span th:text="${role.role}"></span></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>@mdo</td>
    </tr>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate the ${user.roles} on < li > element, like this:

```html
<ul class="dropdown-menu" >
     <li th:each="role : ${user.roles}">
        <a href="#"><span th:text="${role.role}"></span></a>
     </li>
</ul>
```